# Sqoop --boundary-query

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

I have data set as below. Can someone help me to import data to hdfs using sqoop boundary query, Using the column (id) which is having duplicate keys.

```
mysql> select id,name,age from employee;

id   name age   
1   A    30

2   B    35

3   C     40

4   D    23

5   E    26 

1   A    24

2   B    16

3   C     78

4   G    66

3   H    56  

4   A     63

20  C     58

13  F     47

2   A     49 

3   B    60
```

Comment: this is how i tried .hadoop@hadoop:~$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/practice --username root --password hadoop --table employee --boundary-query "select 1,20 from employee" -m 4 --split-by id;

Comment: we should have primary key in the table field for specifing the boundary..

Comment: `--boundary-query` is for splitting data among multiple mappers. By default, it is  `select min(<split-by>), max(<split-by>) from <table name> `. On the basis of min and max values it create range queries and fire them simultaneously from multiple mappers. I am not able to understand what you want to achieve.